# Are these two systems equivalent?

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, maxwell-equations, relative-motion, electromagnetic-induction

1) a charge is placed next to a conducting wire with an electrical current  being carried through it.

2) a moving charge is placed next to a conducting wire such that it is traveling at the same velocity as the electrical current.

situation 1), there is no force on the charge

situation 2), there is a magnetic force on the charge

yet situation 1 can be recreated in situation 2 if we simply speed up the frame of velocity to move with the current. So what really happens? does the current attract a still charge?

Comment: I deleted a comment discussion. If you want to answer a question, please use *answers*, not comments.

Answer (score 0):

For Situation #2, we need to consider two reference frames:  the "lab frame", where the charge is moving, and the "charge frame", where it's not.  In the lab frame, there is a current in the wire, but the wire contains no net charge.  We can model this by saying that the wire contains two types of charge:  positive charges at rest, and negative charges in motion.  The charge densities $\lambda_+$ and $\lambda_-$ of these types of charge are the same *in the lab frame*, but not in their respective rest frames (since they are moving at different velocities.)

If we now switch into the "charge frame", the charge densities both change.  But, importantly, since these two charge densities have different rest frames, they will *not* have the same charge density in the "charge frame".  This means that the wire will have a net charge in the "charge frame".  (This is what  @WillyBillyWilliams was correctly trying to point out to you in a now-deleted comment argument.)

In other words, Situation #2 as observed in the "charge frame" is **not** equivalent to Situation #1.  In Situation #2 in the charge frame, the wire has a net charge and therefore feels an electric force from the wire.  In Situation #1, the wire has no net charge, and so there is no force on the charge.

To see that this leads to the correct qualitative and quantitative behaviour for the magnetic & electric forces, take a look at Section 5.9 of Purcell & Morin's *Electricity & Magnetism*, 3rd ed. (Purcell originated this way of looking at electric & magnetic fields, I believe), or Section 12.3.1 of Griffiths's *Introduction to Electrodynamics*, 4th ed.

Comment: So I'm guessing this is sort of the reason for the difference between the two situations: when the current is induced by a voltage, somehow the charge densities balance each other out. But when the current is created by relative motion, charge densities can remain changed. I can't explain why but thank you for the clear answer